# Google Cloud Storage supports OCR?

Tags: java, sdk, google-cloud-storage

Google Cloud Storage have a search mechanism to find image files using OCR (Optical Character Recognition)? For example, it is possible to search image file  documents in Google Cloud Storage, by their contents? Like in Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage does not currently support searching via Optical Character Recognition.